# Group of circle segment buttons for a compass

Tags: button, canvas, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a compass in flutter and have no idea where to start with the following layout.

https://i.postimg.cc/ZqtZ22bJ/Screen-Shot-2018-11-15-at-4-25-17-PM.png

Each segment acts as a button that changes colour when selected.

Thanks in advance